# Which version of the cgs system in publication from 1983

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, units

I am currently implementing the model proposed in [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-3697(83)90035-5) publication (1983). I already figured out, that it probably uses cgs units. (The units of $1/\epsilon_0$ would be missing in eq. (24,25), if it were SI units.). To get the actual numbers, i would like to find out, which version of the cgs system is used. The value of the electric charge would then change accordingly.

Is there a way to deduce the variant of the cgs system (EMU or ESU or Gaussian units) from the remaining formulas in the publication?

Maybe someone can see it from a formula for the square of a wavevector $q$:
$$q^2=4\pi e^2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial \epsilon } $$
where $e$ is the electron charge, $f$ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution and $\epsilon$ is the respective energy scale.

Comment: The article is behind a paywall, so I can’t read it. However, in my experience, Gaussian units, not ESU or EMU, are by far the most commonly used EM extension of CGS. So I suggest comparing the formulas in the article against Gaussian formulas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between emu and esu?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/248042/)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the related question. I was aware of it, but it does not answer the question. Unfortunately, there are no equations (such as Maxwell's equations) to compare with in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

In 1983 article probably used Gaussian units. If you give us one or two formulas, I can tell you for sure.

Comment: From your answer and @G. Smith comment, I assume that they probably use Gaussian units.